# numericDeriv alters result of eval in R?

Tags: r, eval, differentiation

I've run into something unexpected (for me, maybe). Take a look at the code bellow:

```
> env1 = new.env()
> env1$x = rnorm(10)
> env1$a = 3
> eval(quote(x^a), env1)
 [1]   0.26046508   1.37188255  -0.17077313   0.25959068  -3.38565765
 [6]   0.11537940  -0.06051991  -1.13542624  16.84291641 -10.60959041
> numericDeriv(quote(x^a), "a", env1)
Error in numericDeriv(quote(x^a), "a", env1) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
> eval(quote(x^a), env1)
 [1]  0.2604651  1.3718826        NaN  0.2595907        NaN  0.1153794
 [7]        NaN        NaN 16.8429171        NaN
> env1$a
[1] 3
> eval(quote(x^a), env1)
 [1]  0.2604651  1.3718826        NaN  0.2595907        NaN  0.1153794
 [7]        NaN        NaN 16.8429171        NaN
> env1$a = 3
> eval(quote(x^a), env1)
 [1]   0.26046508   1.37188255  -0.17077313   0.25959068  -3.38565765
 [6]   0.11537940  -0.06051991  -1.13542624  16.84291641 -10.60959041
```

The error in `numericDeriv` is fine since derivative of x^a wrt a is x^a * log(x) and log is not defined for negative numbers. However, why does it changes the result of `eval(quote(x^a), env1)`?

**Edit 1**

As pointed by @Roland, the `env1$a` changes from 3 to 3.00000004470348. I've also checked that this doesn't happen when `numericDeriv` completes without errors

**Edit 2: Session Info**

As requested by @jay.sf, here is the output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.1
```

**Edit 3**

I'm not sure if the `numericDeriv` function still uses this [C code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/nls.c) but if so, at the very bottom of the page we find

```
for(i = 0, start = 0; i < LENGTH(theta); i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < LENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(pars, i)); j++, start += LENGTH(ans)) {
    SEXP ans_del;
    double origPar, xx, delta;

    origPar = REAL(VECTOR_ELT(pars, i))[j];
    xx = fabs(origPar);
    delta = (xx == 0) ? eps : xx*eps;
    REAL(VECTOR_ELT(pars, i))[j] += rDir[i] * delta;
    PROTECT(ans_del = eval(expr, rho));
    if(!isReal(ans_del)) ans_del = coerceVector(ans_del, REALSXP);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    for(k = 0; k < LENGTH(ans); k++) {
      if (!R_FINITE(REAL(ans_del)[k]))
        error(_("Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model"));
      REAL(gradient)[start + k] = rDir[i] * (REAL(ans_del)[k] - REAL(ans)[k])/delta;
    }
    REAL(VECTOR_ELT(pars, i))[j] = origPar;
  }
}
```

and we can see that this behavior, apparently, comes from the inner most for loop. Maybe one quick fix would be changing the `if` in the inner most to

```
if (!R_FINITE(REAL(ans_del)[k])) {
  REAL(VECTOR_ELT(pars, i))[j] = origPar;
  error(_("Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model"));
}
```

I have reported to the author listed on `?numericDeriv`.

Comment: I can reproduce this with R 4.0.1 (on Win10). The call to `numericDeriv` changes the value of `env1$a` to 3.00000004470348. I would say this is a bug, it should not do that. I suggest you report it to the R-devel mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel

Comment: @Roland indeed! I was on hurry and didn't think of checking deeper on what had become of ```env1$a```. Same here, with R 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04,  ```env1$a``` changed to 3.000000044703483581543. Thanks

Comment: This bug is an old one. I can reproduce it in R 3.2.3 (the oldest R version on my machine).

Comment: @Roland I see... I've reported it to the R-devel mailing list as you suggested. Got an email saying it is waiting for approval from a moderator.

Comment: It has been approved, I see it in the archive. Now you can only wait and see if someone bites. (Unfortunately, I'm not good enough with C code to actually identify the reason for this behavior and develop a fix. That would be optimal.)

Comment: Just a comment on Edit 3. I didn't check it is the same that you printed, but you can see the current code here: https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-0-branch/src/library/stats/src/nls.c

Comment: The function is maintained by R-core (see `help("stats")`). You should always bother the maintainer with bug reports, not the author. The bug was confirmed by Luke Tierney and is now in the R bug tracker: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17831

Comment: @iago Thanks. Took a very quick look and it seems to be it.

Comment: @Roland my fault! My attention can be very loose most of the time. I'll apologise if I get any reply from the author. Thanks for all your help!